# How to export to .xls excel format using R

Tags: r

Please, I have this data frame, and I would like to export it in Excel ".xls" file format.

```
df1 <- data.frame(sales_value = c(532489, 20000, 32111, 407536),
                  name = c("John", "Jane", "Jim", "Joan"))
```

I have tried this code.

```
write.table(df1, file = "df1.xls", row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

But it includes unwanted decimals in sales values.

I tried another code below.

````
write.xlsx(df1, "df.xls")
```
But the output exported excel file was internally a .xlsx file format.

Please is there any other way of doing it?
````

Comment: (1) Why tag [tag:dplyr] when you show no code from that package and it doesn't do anything with xls/xlsx files? (2) _Assuming_ the `openxlsx` package (which you need to explicitly state, both in the question and as the tag [tag:openxlsx]), it only supports xlsx. The two formats share _nothing_, there is no compatibility between them, so it is unfortunately not safe to assume that. (3) Is there a reason you _need_ `.xls` instead of `.xlsx`? The latter is supported (in my experience) in far more tools than the former.

Comment: My mistake in tagging the wrong package. I need the .xls because the online service I need to upload the excel only accepts that format. Thanks

Comment: That stinks ... I don't know of an easy way to create `.xls`: `writexl`, `xlsx`, `openxlsx`, and `XLConnect` all advertise `xlsx` and don't mention `xls` directly. The closest I've found is `readxl::read_xls` which _can_ read the format but not write to it. (For more context, https://github.com/ropensci/writexl/issues/11, will-not-support.)

Comment: If you aren't afraid of python, you could use https://pypi.org/project/csv2xls/ to convert a CSV into XLS and upload _that_. (I've never used it, just found it on a quick search.) Searching for `csv2xls` returns other possibilities as well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following approach can be considered. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(openxlsx)

df1 <- data.frame(sales_value = c(532489, 20000, 32111, 407536),
                  name = c("John", "Jane", "Jim", "Joan"))

write.xlsx(df1, "D:\\df1.xlsx")

path_Excel_File <- "D:\\df1.xlsx"
path_Excel_File_Output <- "D:\\df1.xls"

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlWbk1 <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)

xlWbk1$SaveAs(path_Excel_File_Output, -4143) # Save as XLS
```